# Allow other users to see applications

Tags: support, jobs

My HR manager has posted a job on Careers and is forwarding me applications to review (as I'm the hiring manager), but I cannot see those applications using my Stack Exchange account (I get a 404 error). Is it possible for her to add me as a member of the organisation with privileges to view applications and applicant's profiles?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Currently the best way to do this is with the **Share Profiles** link in the candidate manager. However, account organizations are in our pipeline.

Comment: Congratulations with [your new job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-now-60-valued-associates-strong/). Let's get you some moderator worthy reputation here on MSO as soon as possible! ;-)